# Clicking the submit button to go to the next tab only changes the URL but not the tab and the component itself. How can I fix?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-router-dom

I have these tabs for Step1 and Step2. In step1, I have this submit button to go to the next tab, it does update the URL, but the component does not update. It still stays on tab1. How can I fix this?

I kind of wanted to direct the user to the Step2 tab once the user has clicked the `submit` button in `Step1`

I recreated this in codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-cloud-uxfe97?file=/src/Page.js

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Link to="/page">
        <button>Click this to go to the page</button>
      </Link>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/page" element={<Page />}>
          <Route path="step1" element={<Step1 />} />
          <Route path="step2" element={<Step2 />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Tabs**

```
function TabPanel(props) {
  const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <div
      role="tabpanel"
      hidden={value !== index}
      id={`simple-tabpanel-${index}`}
      aria-labelledby={`simple-tab-${index}`}
      {...other}
    >
      {value === index && (
        <Box sx={{ p: 3 }}>
          <Typography component="span">{children}</Typography>
        </Box>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

TabPanel.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node,
  index: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  value: PropTypes.number.isRequired
};

function a11yProps(index) {
  return {
    id: `simple-tab-${index}`,
    "aria-controls": `simple-tabpanel-${index}`
  };
}

const Ordering = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  const paths = ["/page/step1", "/page/step2"];
  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
    navigate(paths[newValue]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Box sx={{ borderBottom: 1, borderColor: "divider" }}>
        <Tabs
          value={value}
          onChange={handleChange}
          aria-label="basic tabs example"
        >
          <Tab
            label="Step 1"
            {...a11yProps(0)}
            component={Link}
            to={`/page/step1`}
          />
          <Tab
            label="Step 2"
            {...a11yProps(1)}
            component={Link}
            to={`/page/step2`}
          />
        </Tabs>
      </Box>

      <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
        <Step1 />
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
        <Step2 />
      </TabPanel>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Ordering;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in the `Step1` component, it is navigating to `"/page/Step2"` instead of `"/page/step2".

```
const Step1 = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    navigate("/page/step2"); // <-- fix target path
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        step1
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

The main issue with `Page` component is that is not "listening" for external route changes. You'll need to listen for these and manually update the `value` state to match the current path.

Example:

```
const Ordering = () => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation(); // <-- current path
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  const paths = useMemo(() => ["/page/step1", "/page/step2"], []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const value = paths.indexOf(pathname);
    setValue(value !== -1 ? value : 0); // <-- set the value to match path
  }, [pathname, paths]);

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
    navigate(paths[newValue]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Box sx={{ borderBottom: 1, borderColor: "divider" }}>
        <Tabs
          value={value}
          onChange={handleChange}
          aria-label="basic tabs example"
        >
          <Tab
            label="Step 1"
            {...a11yProps(0)}
            component={Link}
            to={`/page/step1`}
          />
          <Tab
            label="Step 2"
            {...a11yProps(1)}
            component={Link}
            to={`/page/step2`}
          />
        </Tabs>
      </Box>

      <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
        <Step1 />
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
        <Step2 />
      </TabPanel>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit clicking-the-submit-button-to-go-to-the-next-tab-only-changes-the-url-but-not-th]